# Use server-side error handling for website (highlighting input field)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to do error handling using ajax-post jquery. The code I have is give below:-

HTML :

```
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="Update" id="update" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Now, I want to highlight sections of website contorl (e.g input field) with red-rectangle when there is an input validation error. I can use regex on server side to detect input validation but can I have the end-user notice his errors when he submits the web-page.

For a formal example see [US-cert incident reporting form](https://www.us-cert.gov/forms/report)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I think I have not been very clear with my UI requirements. When a user-hits submit and if there is an input validation error. I want this code to appear on top of page

```
<div class="messages error">
<h2 class="element-invisible">Error message</h2>
One or more of the responses is incomplete or invalid. Please review and correct those         
questions marked with
<b>Error</b>
</div>
```

Also,adjacent to input field (e.g name) should appear as

Error: Name 
Followed with highlighting of the control in red.

**UPDATE#1**

Progess on server-side 
I have defined a php file which accepts from data using action element.The results of all controls on which input validation in required is stored in an array defined in php. This part work I have verified using echo on effected control elements. I just need to pass these elements back to client side.

But the code hasn't be returned (tested) in ajax code because there seems to be some problem in processing of .ajax function. Here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#edit-next").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fname = $("#item_01").val();
    var lname = $("#item_02").val();
    var phone = $("#item_03").val();
    var status = $("#item_11").val();
    //var timeone = $("#item_12").val();


    //var lname = $("#last_name").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + fname + '&last_name=' + lname;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
        url: 'validate.php',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
   });
   });
```

The html code for form action is

```
<form action="" method="post" id="incident-report-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"><font color="red"><i><noscript>Javascript is disabled in your browser.  This will cause some areas of the form to be unavailable.  Enable Javascript to access the complete form.</noscript></i></font></p><div id="package-header-message">
```

I think Jquery code is not considering the form submission event. When I click on the submit button nothing happens the page stays there it doesn't echo anything in validate.php file.

[PASEBIN validate.php](http://pastebin.com/LqLzD9yB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to return a specific value (or Object) from your `insert.php` file.

I have created a basic example that is for a return value in the format of :

```
ctrlID1&ctrlID2&ctrlID3&ctrlID4
```

Example :

```
    $("#update").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&last_name=' + last_name;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'Text',
            url: 'insert.php',
            success: function (data) {
                //Split the returned string into an array
                var ctrlArray = data.split('&');
                //Itterate over each item of the array
                $.each(ctrlArray, function (index, item) {
                    //Set each control to have a red border
                    $('#' + item).css({ border: '1px solid red' });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

What I have done is modify the `$.ajax` call by adding the `dataType` of text (because this example expects a string) and modified the `success` function to handle the return data and set the borders of the controls.

Comment: Great! Thanks Nunners. But the validation is performed on client-side I want to be done in insert.php file?

Comment: @user2820931 Oh ok. If you are validating the controls in `insert.php` you will need to return something that gives the client the control IDs of what is incorrect. How are you planning on doing this?

Comment: @user2820931 Please see my updated answer with an example, this example is specific to a certain return format, you may need to modify it if you wish to work with a different return format.

Comment: @user2820931 You can easily add that to the example I've created for you, but you need to return something from your `insert.php` to let the client know which of the fields are incorrect, could you give me an example of what you are returning?

Comment: Yeah I got it. The return value you specfied above would be set in (else) case where there is input validation error. Some basic validation I want to do is ip-address and port. I don't have any problem with writing regex for them, its just the display (UI) I'm worried about. Also, in code you have given data-type as text, what If in (real) code I'm allowing user to input integer number as well. For e.g it could be name + IP address in dataString variable. On serverside I have to split the string and save into array for regex to take place.

Comment: @user2820931 - Integer format is irrelevant since text is any character possible. It will allow integers. I don't need to know anything about how you validate the fields, just simply what you return once validation is done, i.e. When validation is done, what do you send to the client to let it know that it's done?

Comment: for your code for control rendering (highlighting) to take place, I need to pass the exact item for which the control has to be effected. So I would be returning the name of effected input (e.g #name etc) to ajax. For the message part which would appear on the html page I have included in UPDATE section on my thread.  For postive use-case I would be just returning the summary of his input (in case he wants to edit) if this is not required he will complete his request by clicking final submission button.

Comment: Nunners you ok with explaination?

Comment: @user2820931 For your example could you simply run your code for both cases (one with error, and one without) and tell me what you get in the `data` object of the success ajax function? This is all I need, I understand what you want but without the data I can't help you any further.

Comment: Further the alert(fname) works but not on alert(data) I think the ajax is not sending anything out to be processed by validate.php

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Console? You may have to specify the `dataType: 'Text'` in your Ajax call because by default it expects a JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what console means over here. I'm using expression web for debug, firebug for mozilla and wamp as web-server. The error for me meant I'm getting no java-script popup on alert(data). Another thing I'm little confused on instead of saving each form input (from inputbox,radio button) to be sent to server can I not submit all the form data instead. Also in the form action="" its kept empty is that okay for you?

Comment: See my question update at (end) I have also included pastebin of php file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is solved. The returned data gives / returns me the effected  input-id. But I want to use existing css files to generate me error definition. Can u help?

Comment: @Nunners can you review my revised thread?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331034/how-to-re-create-summary-page-of-a-site-for-your-own-use